# Meteor + CSS not loading up correctly

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, meteorite

I am using bootstrap and a small custom CSS page, however for some reason Meteor just decides to ignore the custom CSS file but it's loading bootstrap.

I'm placing all my CSS on the `public` folder, however I am a little confused. Should it be in the `client` folder?

The custom CSS file is called `main.css` so it will be loaded last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, It is working! I just placed it under the `lib` directory inside the `client` folder.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in `lib` directory. Just put it somewhere inside `client`. Public should be used for things like images, or just larger files, which are going to be loaded only when they are needed, not at your app startup.

Comment: I ended up doing that. :) Thanks for the tip.